# Unsure as to how the code is working to return true or false

Tags: java, boolean

Using the very basic code (and I'm sure you'll see my level of knowledge from the code), I can't work out what the code is doing. I understand how the conditionals work. 
If I had been writing the code from scratch, I'd have used if loops, obviously unnecessary! 
How it the code returning true or false though? Is it a default behaviour of Java?

```
public class Helloworld{

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println(2<3);
            System.out.println(2==3);
            System.out.println(2!=3);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `2 < 3` returns `true`, what exactly is your question? It's really unclear. Maybe the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1) can clarify some of your thoughts.

Comment: Why would loops be appropriate at all here?

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Comment: What did you expect it to print? I mean if not boolean were you expecting 0 / 1 ? ( As in C )

Comment: You need to read [the tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) if you're wondering about those.

Comment: Strictly speaking the program doesn't "return" anything.  Rather it writes some lines to standard output, and then exits with the default exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2<3`, `2==3`, and `2!=3` are all *compile-time evaluable constant expressions*.

The *compiler* will evaluate them as `true`, `false`, and `true` respectively. These are `boolean` types in Java and `println` has an appropriate overload for that type.

Comment: Sorry. A badly worded question but you gave me the info. I was after.

Answer (score 2):

```
2<3
```

is a conditional statement, which either returns `true`, or `false`, and that is printed.

The same applies for:

```
2==3
```

and

```
2!=3
```

Your output should be:

> true  
>   false 
>   true

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(2<3);// this returns true.
System.out.println(2==3);// this returns false.
System.out.println(2!=3);// this return true.
```

go through this link for more info on how comparison (Equality and Relational operators) works in java  ...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html